# How can i add css class to .cs file dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I am working on asp.net c#. I using a repeater to display elements . I have a class that is referring divs inside css , my css class is 
Wjen i add 5 elemnts content-5 should be added to above class . How can i do this ?

here is the code:

```css
tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-1,.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-2,.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-3,.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-4 {
    z-index:100;
    -ms-filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition:opacity ease-out .2s .1s;
    -moz-transition:opacity ease-out .2s .1s;
    -o-transition:opacity ease-out .2s .1s;
    -ms-transition:opacity ease-out .2s .1s;
    transition:opacity ease-out .2s;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm confused: is this c# or css?

Comment: tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-1,
.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-2,
.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-3,
.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-4{
 z-index: 100;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -o-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s

Comment: Don't put code in the comment, put it in your question

Comment: @user1511098 not to mention this is a mess. Code in the question, not the comments.

Comment: At the moment I fear the question makes little sense. `.cs` is (in this case) server-side logic code, `.css` is client-side rendering rules. If the `.cs` is generating html, then just add some `class="theCssName"`...

Comment: Can you please include your _relevant_ .cs code as well? I don't think anyone here understands where c# enters into this question!

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching the problem from the wrong way.

You shouldn't be adding classes to the css styles. The elements you add to the page dynamically through c# code should all have the same css class.

CSS shouldn't be dynamic ever (IMO).